# How to allow a file download from a control wrapped under UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, httpresponse, datalist

I have a Datalist control which display thumbnails and a download icon (ImageButton) under it, Datalist is wrapped under UpdatePanel, When user clicks on download icon I call the following function to allow file to be downloaded at user end

```
    protected void dtlSearchDetails_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "dtlImgDownload")
        {
            downloadFile(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), "~/uploads/primary/");
        }
}
```

function :

```
public void downloadFile(string fileName, string filePath)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
    Response.WriteFile(filePath + fileName);
}
```

Now since the `ImageButton` / `Datalist` is wrapped inside `UpdatePanel`, I have registered it as a postback control with the `ScriptManager` on `Page_Load`

```
if (dtlSearchDetails.Items.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataListItem li in dtlSearchDetails.Items)
    {
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)li.FindControl("dtlImgDownload");
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(img);
   }
}
```

Now when I click the download icon nothing happens and I get this following error in console :

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this
>   error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(),
>   response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

But,

There are other controls on the same page like search button, which are outside this UpdatePanel but I have registered them as

```
<trigger>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnKeySearch" />
</trigger>
```

inside the same updatePanel.

When I click on this search button and then click the download Icon it behaves perfectly fine as expected (download's the file at client) without and error in console.

I am not able to find out the cause behind this workaround.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `ImageButton` is inside a `DataList` so you have to do the `RegisterPostBackControl` inside your `DataList`'s `ItemDataBound` event.

```
protected void dtlSearchDetails_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var imgBtn = e.Item.FindControl("dtlImgDownload") as ImageButton;
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(imgBtn);
        // your other code goes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure if we can the re-initialize instance of ScriptManager anywhere else besibe the Page_Load, I'll definitely give it a try right away and will update you. Thanks for consideration.

Comment: Ray : It did worked, actually it changed the event other way around, So now when I click on the downloadLink for the first time, It downloads the Image, but when any other button is clicked or the grid is reloaded and I click the download icon again, it gives me the same error, So I think the scrip manager manager is loosing/unregistering the control name.

Comment: @Vishal Sachdeva, you are right. script manager is loosing track of other controls and it can get complicated if you have other controls on the page. try to call the `ItemDataBind` again after your download code, but i don't like that kind of dirty workaround. my second suggestion is to use a `Generic Handler` for the file download. in your `ImageButton`, assign its `href` to `FileDownload.ashx?id=x` and `target=_blank`. this way, you are factoring out the download to another page with a new request. so `UpdatePanel` is not on the way anymore.

Comment: Ray : Well actually you are absolutely right here, my first thought was togo with .ashx handlers only, but i couldn't really found a good tutorial to start with and I kind have a very little experience with net. As a workaround for now I have fixed this by keeping the register code in Page_load as well as inside ItemDataBound event, working well, but as you said these are dirty work arounds rather than a proper approach :) .. Thanks once again for taking out time.